# Saving big images one after another memory deallocation on iOS

Tags: ios, image, memory, memory-management

I have a strange problem while saving number of big images (from camera) to the filesystem one after another in loop.

If I place `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];` in each loop, than memory is released just fine after every image processing. But without that sleep interval, memory allocation increases above the roof and eventually app crashes...

Could someone please explain how to avoid this or to deallocate memory after each loop?

Btw, I'm developing on iOS 5...

This is the my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (NSDictionary *imageInfo in self.imageDataArray) {

        [assetslibrary assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
            CGImageRef imageRef = [[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage];
            if (imageRef) {
                [sharedAppSettingsController saveCGImageRef:imageRef toFilePath:filePath];
                imageRef = nil;
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
                //CFRelease(imageRef);
            }
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"booya, cant get image - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }];

    }

    // tell the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //do smth on finish
    });
});
```

And this is the method for saving CGImage to FS:

```
- (void)saveCGImageRef:(CGImageRef)imageRef toFilePath:(NSString *)filePath {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, imageRef, nil);

        bool success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to write image to %@", filePath);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Written to file: %@",filePath);
        }
        CFRelease(destination);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you wrap your loop in an @autorelease{} block ?

Comment: I have wrapped the code inside and outside the loop with no effect. App still consumes above 20MB of ram and than crashes. Anything else to look for?

Comment: Can someone please look at the code if am I doing smth wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call "assetForURL" in a for loop. This method will begin loading all of your images simultaneously each on a separate thread. You should begin loading 1 image and in completion block continue with loading the next one. I suggest you use some kind of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem isn't in saveImageRef method but with ALAssetRepresentation object:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage];
```

`imageRef` allocates a huge amount of memory after reading each original image from Photo library. That's kind a logical.

But I want that this `imageRef` object to be released at the end of each loop and not whenever ARC decides to release it.

So I tried to `imageRef = nil;` after each loop but nothing is changed.

Is there any other way to release allocated memory at the end of each loop?